# Wie übersetze ich "Bootstrap"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

In der Dokumentation von [vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/) steht folgender Satz:

> You can modify its properties listed below before bootstrapping your application:

Wie kann ich "to bootstrap" am Besten ins Deutsche übersetzen?

**Update 1:** [Hier](https://en.bab.la/dictionary/english-german/bootstrap) wird es mit "urladen" übersetzt. Ich habe aber diesen Ausdruck nie gehört (hört sich nach der Mainframe-Ära an).

Comment: _Stiefelschleife_ noch Fragen?

Comment: Ernsthaft: Belasse es einfach bei _Bootstrap_, jeder der das verstehen muss versteht es. Eine (schlechte) Übersetzung macht es nur schlimmer.

Comment: *Urlader* oder *urladen* ist perfekt, wenn auch bereits ein bißchen altertümlich. Aber es müsste eigentlich auch von jedem verstanden werden, der es verstehen muss.

Comment: *Urladen* ist korrekt, wenn es sich um den Vorgang während eines Systemstarts handelt. Im Zusammenhang mit Vue würde ich aber eher *starten* oder *initialisieren* sagen.

Comment: Wenn das irgendjemand verstehen soll, der die deutsche Informatik-Fachsprache nicht versteht, würde ich es bei *bootstrap* belassen. Ein deutscher Text mit englischem (internationalem) Fachvokabular lässt sich noch verhältnismäßig leicht nachvollziehen, wenn man ein bisschen Ahnung von der Materie hat. Aber mit selten gebrauchten Übersetzungen wird es schwierig!

Comment: _Bootstrapping_ hat es immerhin zu einem eigenen [Enzyklopädie-Eintrag](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(Programmierung)) gebracht - eventuell ist eine komplette Übersetzung also gar nicht nötig, sondern nur eine eingedeutschte Version des Verbs?

Comment: @tofro Bootstrapping bezeichnet aber beispielsweise auch den Entwicklungszyklus, der darin mündet, dass Version v+1 einer Programmiersprache in Version v derselben Programmiersprache entwickelt werden kann. Da passt "urladen" dann wiederum nicht gut.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Den Begriff »urladen« gibt es tatsächlich, aber

a) ist damit v.a. der Startprozess eines Computers gemeint, passt also hier nicht, und

b) ist er so historisch, dass ihn kaum jemand in einem Alter diesseits der Rente verwenden würde. Beim gefühlten Alterdurchschnitt der JavaScript-Meute würdest du vermutlich auf komplettes Unverständnis stoßen.

In der IT-Fachsprache musst du damit leben, dass es für viele Fachbegriffe – z.B. *to bootstrap* – keine geläufige deutsche Übersetzung gibt. Um keine Bedeutung zu verfälschen, bleibt meistens nur die Option, den englischen Begriff stehen zu lassen.